# Embed forms in symfony and save entities

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to embed forms in symfony but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have two entities. User and Color

User.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Color", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $color;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }

    public function setColor($color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
    }
}
```

Color.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Color
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Color
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

The form is rendered fine but when I try to save the entity I get an error saying `Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Color could not be converted to string`

Here's my controller

.......

```
 $user = new User();

        $form = $this->createForm(new SelectionType(), $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return new Response(sprintf('ID %s', $user->getId()));
        }
```

SelectionType.php

```
........
 ->add('color', new ColorType())
....
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `__toString()` method to your `Color` class

```
// all declaration here
class Color
{
  // all properties here

  public function __toString()
  {
    return $this->name();
  }

  // all getters and setters here
}
```

This error is caused because Symfony's Form try to give a "representation for GUI" of your object and, if you don't specify anything else into FormBuilder (or if you don't use any DataTransformer), it will search for a string representation of object (that you can obtain with `__toString()` method)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I no longer get the error. Now I have another issue. When I save user entity I get extra record in color table, behavior that I don't need. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @Vodokan what do you mean with "extra record"?

Comment: Table Color has three records Green, Yellow and Blue (which are represented by drop down in the form). When `$this->persist($user)` is executed the table color gets  a new row with the selected value from the drop down so it becomes Green, Yellow, Blue Yellow which is not what I want. I just want to keep reference between user and color tables with the selected color.

Comment: In this case you need an extra table (for relation) to keep this information (i suppose)

Comment: In this case you should use Form Collections and relationships would be OneToMany and ManyToOne for User and Color Entities respectively. You can read more in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).